# SASS Module Error when trying to use @use rule

Tags: sass, node-sass, scss-mixins

I am new to SCSS and having an issue using the @use rule.

**sass/helpers/_variables.scss**

```
$companyColor: #d60048;
```

**header/header.scss**

```
@use '../sass/helpers/_variables' as variables;

.app-header {
    background-color: variables.$companyColor;
}
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Header/Header.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-2!./src/Header/Header.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...olor: variables": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$companyColor;"
        on line 4 of C:\MyProject\Client\src\Header\Header.scss
>>     background-color: variables.$companyColor;
   -------------------------------^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using *Dart Sass*? Seems like this is the only version that supports the `@use` keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure. I installed the `node-sass` package and ran into this: https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@use` keyword is unfortunately [not supported](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2886) in *node-sass* (yet). Lets hope that they bring support in the near future. Till then, you can use the `@import` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I had to remove node-sass and sass (global). Then I installed sass (local). And you need to replace compiler

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              // Prefer `dart-sass`
              implementation: require('sass'),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```